C++ writing and reading last line of file
I need to read numbers from file, calculate sum and write sum on last line, then read sum back from file. It works okayish up until i need to read last line back from file. Can't get it to work.
So, two problems:

If i do file.open(file_name, ios::in|ios::out|ios::app) , i believe i should be able to read as well as write the last row of the file. Can't get it to write. Example below:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int value, sum = 0;
    fstream file;
    string file_name = "values.txt";

    file.open(file_name, ios::in | ios::out | ios::app); 

        while(file >> value) {
        sum = sum + value; }

        file << "\n" << sum; // does not write to file.

    file.close();
    file.open(file_name, ios::in | ios::ate);

        file >> value;
        cout << "sum is " << value; 
}

But when i close and open file in between, it does work.
{
    int value, sum = 0;
    fstream file;
    string file_name = "values.txt";

    file.open(file_name, ios::in); 

        while(file >> value) {
        sum = sum + value; }

    file.close();
    file.open(file_name, ios::out | ios::app);

        file << "\n" << sum; // now writes to file.

    file.close();
    file.open(file_name, ios::in | ios::ate);

        file >> value;
        cout << "sum is " << value; 
}

The question(s) here is, why? What does the closing and opening do that i haven't been able to figure out? There has to be some way to reset "something" so i don't have to re-open the whole file, no?

I can't read back the previously written line. I'm under the impression that ios::ate should "seek to the end of stream immediately after open". However, in this case it returns the second to last value. Or maybe "value" never gets the last number but instead remembers the last read value from the previous segment. Maybe my thinking is just wrong here.
...

    file.open(file_name, ios::in | ios::ate);

        file >> value; // does not take last value from file.
        cout << "sum is " << value; //prints second to last value from file, or remembers value    from previous segment.
}



Any help, tips, hints or anything that could get me forward with this?

while(file >> value)  this loop will only stop when file is in an error state or hit the end of the file. All subsequent reads or writes will not read or write until you reset the state of the stream

Thanks! Googling stream reset led me to clear(), and that worked like a charm.  I'll need to read up more on stream behaviour.  Still not able to read last line from file though.

If the read cursor is at the end of the file (due to ios::ate), there's nothing more to read. The end doesn't mean the last line, because streams are not line-oriented. You can either seek backwards from the end until you find a newline, or just remember where the end of file was just before you appended your new line.

the fact that streams is not easy to work with in c++ has been motivation to create whole new languages afaik ;)

In practice it is safer to just read the original file to memory, move the original file to a backup, change the content in memory, and then write a new file. And delete the backup if you want. This pattern has nothing to do with C++, but with file handling in general. If you need to update stuff on the fly, use a database not a file.

All rigth! thank you all! I got it working with peek/seekg, which i believe to be a bit of a dirty fix. This was nevertheless an extremely important lesson in stream behaviour.

I got it working with .clear() and .peek/.seekg. Thank you all for pointing me in the right direction. I've let myself understand that this is porbably not a very good fix, at least not for larger files, or when i need to find a specific line in the middle of the file. It did make me understand stream behaviour a litle bit better, so that's a win in my book.
Also, i was reminded during my research, that i should probably get a rubber duck.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() 
{
    int value, sum = 0;
    fstream file;
    string file_name = "values.txt";
    
    file.open(file_name, ios::in | ios::out | ios::app); 
    
        while(file >> value) {  
            sum = sum + value; 
            }

        file.clear();   // clears the stream state flags.
        file << sum << "\n"; 
        
        file.seekg(-2, ios::cur);   //move pointer so to not see the last newline.
        while (file.peek() != '\n') {   //seek for newline before last value. 
            file.seekg(-1, ios::cur);
            };
        
        file >> value;
        cout << "sum is " << value; 
}
  

